# Interpretation of Fisher's exact test confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, odds-ratio, fishers-exact-test

I am having difficulties with the interpretation of Fisher's exact test confidence interval. I have a contingency table with some numbers below:

[image: table data]

I perform Fisher's exact test:

```
fisher.test(table(data$`nb loca` > 1, data$Rechute))
```

The test gives me the following result :

```
p-value = 0.03127
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1

95 percent confidence interval:
  0.9321775 18.3647578

sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  4.286446
```

From what I understand, I can conclude that these variables are not independent and that the odd ratio for my sample is about 4.3. However the 95% confidence interval for the odd ratios includes 1. How can I interpret this? How can the p-value be < 0.05 with such a 95% CI for the odd ratios?

Comment: See [Fay (2010), "Confidence intervals that match Fisher's exact or Blaker's exact tests", *Biostatistics*, **11**, 2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2852239).

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495142